# Wildcards in C# generic constraints

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance, generic-constraints

I'm aware that C# doesn't have generic wildcards, and that a similar effect can be achieved by generic methods, but I need to use a wildcard in a field and can't work out if there is any way to encode it.

```
List<State<Thing>> list;

void AddToList<T>() where T : Thing {
    list.Add(new State<T>());
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work because the object being added isn't of type `State<Thing>`, it's of type `State<T> where T : Thing`. Is it possible to adjust the most internal type of the list to be the Java equivalent of `? extends Thing` rather than just `Thing`?

Comment: Can you declare your list as `List<State<T>> where T : Thing`?

Comment: @abatishchev: maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @konrad: [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8428752/41956)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that C# 4 does have additional variance support, but it does not apply in the `List<T>` case, for various reasons (has both "in" and "out" methods, and is a class).

I think, however, the way to address this is with something like:

```
interface IState { // non-generic
    object Value { get; } // or whatever `State<Thing>` needs
}
class State<T> : IState {
    public T Value { get { ...} } // or whatever
    object IState.Value { get { return Value; } }
}
```

and

```
List<IState> list; ...
```

which *will* then allow you to add any `State<T>`. It doesn't really use much of the `T`, and a cast would be needed to get from the `object` to `T`, but .... it will at least work.

Comment: I really don't understand why can't I cast as the following: `(State<Thing>)new State<T>` while `T : Thing`! But can `(Thing)new T()`

Comment: @abatishchev because a `SomeSpecificThing` **is** a `Thing`; but it is *not* true that a `State<SomeSpecificThing>` is a `State<Thing>`. There is no inheritance etc. If it were a generic interface, if **could** potentially be `IState<out Thing>`, in which case the 4.0 variance rules start to apply, and **then** yes, there is a cast from `IState<SomeSpecificThing>` to `IState<Thing>`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this :

```
    interface IState<out T> { }
    class State<T> : IState<T> { }
    class Thing {}

    List<IState<Thing>> list;

    void AddToList<T>() where T : Thing
    {
        list.Add(new State<T>());
    }
```

Comment: I would prefer this, but I can't use C# 4.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your list as the following:

```
class State<T> where T : Thing
{
    ...

    List<State<T>> list = new List<State<T>>();
    // or
    public class StateList<T> : List<State<T>>
    {
         void AddToList(T item);
    }
}
```

then compiler will be able to convert.